# Making card game, need to add JLabels to JPanel at runtime based on how many cards in player's hand

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, grid-layout, playing-cards

In my game, the player's hand will typically be around 5 cards (and a separate `ArrayList`), but can get massive quickly with a lot of "draw cards" options in the game. Everywhere else that cards are displayed, I have them in a `JLabel` which updates to show the image and when clicked, the image moves to the player discard pile and the card is added to the discard `ArrayList`, like this:

```
private void mainDeckMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                      
        ImageIcon mainDeckEmpty = new ImageIcon("C:\\DC Card Game\\src\\DCCardGame\\resources\\Other Cards\\Empty Main Deck.png");

        if (DrawCards.cards.isEmpty())
            mainDeck.setIcon(mainDeckEmpty);

        if (slot1Card == noCard)
        {
            if (!DrawCards.cards.isEmpty())
            {
                slot1Card = DrawCards.drawFromMainDeck();
                lineupSlot1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(slot1Card.getImage()));
                lineupSlot1.setToolTipText(slot1Card.getCardText());
                if (DrawCards.cards.isEmpty())
                mainDeck.setIcon(mainDeckEmpty);
            }
        }
}
```

This is a snippet of code from when the main deck is clicked and it adds cards to the lineup. This works beautifully.

The problem I'm running into is that for the `playerHand` `ArrayList`, I can't figure out how to add a `JLabel` on the fly (when necessary), assign an image to it based on the card drawn, and then assign the actual card object to a variable that can be manipulated. In the example above, I'm assigning it to a predefined variable `slot1Card` so how would I be able to assign a card to a variable when I can't define it at run time OR is there a way to assign all the values shown above (discard image, player hand image, tooltip text, card object, etc) without using a variable? Also, I'm displaying player hand cards in a panel using `GridLayout`, inside a `JScrollPane`.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: More SSCCE - this is the code I just quickly wrote so that on mouseclick it adds cards from the deck to the player hand. This would need to be what is modified to add labels to the jpanel, I believe.

```
private void playerDeckMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    ImageIcon playerDeckEmpty = new ImageIcon("C:\\DC Card       Game\\src\\DCCardGame\\resources\\Other Cards\\Empty Player Deck.png");

    if (DrawCards.player_1_deck.isEmpty())
        playerDeck.setIcon(playerDeckEmpty);

    if (!DrawCards.cards.isEmpty())
        {
            playerHandSlot1Card = DrawCards.drawFromPlayerDeck();
            playerHandSlot1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(playerHandSlot1Card.getImage()));
            playerHandSlot1.setToolTipText(playerHandSlot1Card.getCardText());

            playerHandSlot2Card = DrawCards.drawFromPlayerDeck();
            playerHandSlot2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(playerHandSlot2Card.getImage()));
            playerHandSlot2.setToolTipText(playerHandSlot2Card.getCardText());

            playerHandSlot3Card = DrawCards.drawFromPlayerDeck();
            playerHandSlot3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(playerHandSlot3Card.getImage()));
            playerHandSlot3.setToolTipText(playerHandSlot3Card.getCardText());

            playerHandSlot4Card = DrawCards.drawFromPlayerDeck();
            playerHandSlot4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(playerHandSlot4Card.getImage())); 
            playerHandSlot4.setToolTipText(playerHandSlot4Card.getCardText());

            playerHandSlot5Card = DrawCards.drawFromPlayerDeck();
            playerHandSlot5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(playerHandSlot5Card.getImage()));
            playerHandSlot5.setToolTipText(playerHandSlot5Card.getCardText());
        }
    if (DrawCards.player_1_deck.isEmpty())
        playerDeck.setIcon(playerDeckEmpty);
}
```

Comment: You are not adding to an `ArrayList`...

Comment: @MadPhysicist You're right, and I'm doing a terrible job of explaining what I'm trying to do. I'm going to sit on it for now, think it over and come at it again later. Thank's for your help.

Comment: @bitli Great idea, and I can't believe I didn't see that. I'm still very new, so thank you!

Comment: Sorry but I partially understand your problem. I think you should initialize all cards somewhere (cache class or something) before game starts and collect them when they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating a separate variable for each one of player's cards, use a `List` such as an `ArrayList`. You can create each element of the list as necessary like this:

```
private void playerDeckMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    ImageIcon playerDeckEmpty = new ImageIcon("C:\\DC Card       Game\\src\\DCCardGame\\resources\\Other Cards\\Empty Player Deck.png");

    if (DrawCards.player_1_deck.isEmpty())
        playerDeck.setIcon(playerDeckEmpty);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5 && !DrawCards.cards.isEmpty(); i++)
    {
            playerHandSlotCard = DrawCards.drawFromPlayerDeck();
            playerHandSlot.setIcon(new ImageIcon(playerHandSlot1Card.getImage()));
            playerHandSlot.setToolTipText(playerHandSlot1Card.getCardText());
            playerHandList.add(platerHandSlot);
    }
    if (DrawCards.player_1_deck.isEmpty())
        playerDeck.setIcon(playerDeckEmpty);
}
```

To display the many labels a player's hand contains, you can dynamically add them to a container. Rather than using a `JLabel` to display a player's hand, use a `JPanel` with a `CardLayout`. Whenever the player draw a card, call `panel.add(playerHandSlot)`. If this happens outside the `playerDeckMouseClicked` method, you can use a `for` loop to access the elements of `playerHandList`

```
for(JLabel playerHandSlot : playerHandList) {
    panel.add(playerHandSlot);
}
```

Comment: I'm not saying that's incorrect, but this doesn't make sense to me. Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: Enjoy. You really should post an SSCE.

Comment: thank you for taking the time! I usually do post SSCCE but I wasn't sure I needed it since this was pretty much writing it from the ground up with few defined variables. Also, I'm not sure how your code is different than mine other than the arrayList at the top. The problem I would run into is that 1) I don't know how to create a new label at runtime and 2) it seems like repeatedly adding the same thing to it is going to not work as I would need both the names of the label to modify it and a variable like slot1Card to modify it.

Comment: do not load Image, ImageIcon, Icon or BufferedIMage on runtime, store this Object as local variable

Comment: @mKorbel I actually do, it's stored in a Card variable named slot1Card

Comment: Updated my code at the top, hopefully that explains a little better what I'm trying to do.